# MPI how to create two communicators

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I need to divide the processes into several communicators. In one write even, and in other odd. I wrote the code, but when I run it, I get errors. Help to understand what is a problem. Or tell me on the right way or not. Sorry for bad English.

```
int world_rank, world_size;
int *odd, *even;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

int oddSize = world_size / 2;
int evenSize = world_size - oddSize;
odd = new int[oddSize];
even = new int[evenSize];
MPI_Comm odd_comm, even_comm;
MPI_Group odd_group, even_group, group_world;
MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &group_world);   

for (int i = 0, j = 0, p = 0; i < world_size; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        odd[j] = i;
        j++;
    }
    else
    {
        even[p] = i;
        p++;
    }
}   
MPI_Group_incl(group_world, oddSize, odd, &odd_group);
MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, odd_group, &odd_comm);
}
```

My error logs:

```
job aborted:
[ranks] message

[0] terminated
[1] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Comm_rank: Invalid communicator, error stack:
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_NULL, rank=0x0111FC70) failed
Invalid communicator

[2] terminated

[3] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Comm_rank: Invalid communicator, error stack:
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_NULL, rank=0x009FFDB8) failed
Invalid communicator
[4] terminated
[5] fatal error
Fatal error in MPI_Comm_rank: Invalid communicator, error stack:
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_NULL, rank=0x00BDF7E4) failed
Invalid communicator
---- error analysis -----
[1,3,5,9,17] on DRON
```

Comment: This is begging for `MPI_Comm_split()`

Comment: I need to use MPI_Comm_split () instead of MPI_Comm_create ()? @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: `MPI_Comm_split()` is a way better fit here.

Comment: Could you tell me how to remake my code? I don't understand how to single out the processes in a separate communicator using MPI_Comm_split (). Thank you @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: what have you tried so far ? `man MPI_Comm_split` is a good start ...